# cakePHP 2 not returning jsonp

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, jsonp, cakephp-2.5

Frustration!
I am trying to write angular frontend and CakePHP project. I need cake to return JSONP formatted data. I am new AngularJS and have been working with CakePHP for a while now. CakePHP documentation makes this sound easy (cuz its light on documentation) and all examples online seem to be "not the cake way."

Here is my code (so far)

**Cake Controller**

```
public function index() {
  $this->layout = false;
  $result = array('result_code' => 500, 'result_message' => 'Petitions could not be listed.', 'result_data' => null );
  $this->disableCache();

  $this->Paginator->settings = array('findType' => 'PetitionList', 'limit' => $this->pagination_limit);

  try {
    $result['result_data'] = $this->Paginator->paginate();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = array('result_code' => 501, 'result_message' => 'Request out or range.', 'result_data' => null );
  }

  if (!empty ($result['result_data'])) {
    $result['pagination_limit'] = $this->pagination_limit;
    $result['result_code'] = 200;
    $result['result_message'] = 'Data Success.';
  }

  $this->set( array(
    'result' => $result,
    '_serialize' => 'result',
    '_jsonp' => true,
  ));
 }
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
petitionApp.controller('PetitionListCtrl', function ($scope, PetitionList) {
  $scope.petitions = new PetitionList();
  // $scope.petitions.here()
});

petitionApp.factory('PetitionList', function sigs($http){
  var PetitionList = function makePetitionList() {
    this.signatures = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.paginationCount = 50;
    this.page = 0;
  };

  PetitionList.prototype.more = function more() {
    // check to see if we are in the process of loading data.
    if (this.busy === true) {
      return;
    }
    this.busy = true;

    var moreUrl = '/Petitions/index/page:' + this.page + '.json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
    $http.jsonp(moreUrl)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('sucess');
      console.log(data);

      this.page = this.page + this.paginationCount;
      this.busy = false;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('error');
    })
    .bind(this);
  };

  return PetitionList;
});
```

**Cake Views**
None, I was under the impression CakePHP knows to handle this request as a JSONP.

**Sample of Data**
When I hit my end-point I get this:

```
{
  "result_code": 200,
  "result_message": "Data Success.",
  "result_data": [
    {
      "Petition": {
        "last_name": "Ayala",
        "create_date": "2016-04-08",
        "first_name": "N"
      },
      "Country": {
        "code": "MEX"
      }
    },
    {
      "Petition": {
        "last_name": "United States",
        "create_date": "2016-04-15",
        "first_name": "U"
      },
      "Country": {
        "code": "USA"
      }
    },
    {
      "Petition": {
        "last_name": "Cocos",
        "create_date": "2016-04-15",
        "first_name": "C"
      },
      "Country": {
        "code": "CCK"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pagination_limit": 50
}
```

**Expecting**
The above but wrapped in something like
Callback_123456( ... data here ....);

**I Have Checked**

- Routes.php file has

  Router::parseExtensions('json');

followed by

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

- Controller has
  public $components = array('RequestHandler');

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `?` in your URL, denoting the query string?

Comment: I thought I had that. moreUrl = '/Petitions/index/page:' + this.page + '.json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'; this.page is a int and I have tested with a hardcoded 0.

'/Petitions/index/page:0.json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'

Comment: And the URL is still missing the question mark (`?`)...

Comment: yeah, I am an idiot. My brain kept seeing that as a ?